# Reduce high mysql memory consumption

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm using DO to host my WordPress sites ( Ubuntu 16.04.2 / Nginx / mysql )
I notice that mysql is consuming a lot of memory in each task.
For each site I create a new database (which contains WordPress in MultiSite)

My question is — **how can I fix the high memory consumption from mysql?**

[image: htop screenshot]

Comment: This is a bit broad - there are various articles around the net that provide hints and tips, e.g [here](https://bobcares.com/blog/fix-mysql-high-memory-usage/), [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/24/mysql-server-memory-usage-2/) and [here](http://kb.bodhost.com/mysql-high-memory-usage/). What have you tried?

Comment: You could use a dedicated server for all your databases and serve data from there. It depends where your server is and where you are (clients) visiting from. It may also be not because of the mysqld operation in your htop, but because of poorly written mysql queries. Bit of a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling a bunch of features can reduce memory consumption by half.

Just one the MySql configuration file:

```
sudo vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Then add the below values

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema = OFF
symbolic-links=0
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 32K
max_allowed_packet = 4M
table_open_cache = 8
sort_buffer_size = 128K
read_buffer_size = 512K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 4K
thread_stack = 480K
innodb_file_per_table
max_connections=100
max_user_connections=50
wait_timeout=50
interactive_timeout=50
long_query_time=5
```

Then Stop/Start the MySql

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: An explanation of what this configuration does (any negaive consequence) would be helpful.

Comment: The parameter information should be obtained from the MySQL document since that is the main source of information.